# On the Matrix ITA site, why doesn't Virgin Australia show up in the search results?

Tags: online-resources, flight-search-engines, virgin-australia

Even when being specific, why is Virgin Australia (airline code VA) never available in search results on the Matrix.ITASoftware.com website? Yet sites like Kayak show results from VA?

Routes I was comparing:
SYD (Sydney) to CPT (Cape Town) or JNB (Johannesburg)

Comment: I'm not sure what you tried - a quick sample search for Sydney-Melbourne did return VA as second option.

Comment: and see [here](http://virginaustralia.innosked.com) for an interactive route map, including their codeshare partners.

Comment: @greyshade, Thanks, I was trying SYD (Sydney) to CPT (Cape Town) or JNB (Johannesburg).

Comment: Personally, I don't trust any single flight search engine to include every airline. I now use three search engines in their own tabs when I'm researching flights. They all lack some stuff in the others and include some stuff missing in the others.

Comment: This made me realise that too @hippietrail, so what are your three? Kayak, ITA, and?

Comment: @DaviddCeFreitas: I try new sites I hear about. I like Adioso, SkyScanner, and Momondo. I also use Matrix sometimes. Each site also has some other extra or missing features so it depends what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the two routes that you detailed Virgin Australia does not have any of its own flights.

However it has a codeshare agreement with Singapore Airlines on those two routes, which means you could purchase a VA flight and not travel on a Va plane.

I did a quick check on the VA website and the codeshare flights are shown.

Kayak uses matrix ita, but also pulls fare data from over 400 sites, so it is likely that VA have not offered that fare grouping to ita, but is offering it on its own system, or through another partner.

---

Kayak case study (from ita website)

About Kayak

Kayak.com, the largest Travel 2.0 site in the world, is a global Internet media company operating Kayak.com, Sidestep.com, TravelPost.com and TravelSearch.com. Kayak.com and SideStep.com display results from more than 400 travel sites, providing prices and itineraries for hundreds of airlines.....

(There is more to this quote but I think it covers what I want to say)